# default value for file input form when update image in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Using Laravel 5.8, I'm trying to make update data in laravel, the data is contained images, when the form update did not get a new image, laravel displays an error, that the image is null,
can I make the old image as the default value for the file input?

this is my controller

```
public function UploadEdit(Request $request, Books $book,$id_book){
    $book = Books::find($id_book);
    global $old_image;
    $old_image = public_path("img/books/". $book->image);
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        if (File::exists($old_image)) { 
            unlink($old image);
        }

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image_name = time()."_".$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('img/books',$image_name);
        $book->image=$image_name;
    }else{
        $book->image = $old_image;
    }

    DB::table('books')->where('id_book',$request->id_book,$image_name)->update([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'image' => $request->image = $image_name,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'description' => $request->description
    ]);



    return redirect('/books');
}
```

this is input file from my form :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" id="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="{{ asset("img/books/$book->image") }}">
    <img src="{{ asset("img/books/$book->image") }}" width="150">
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the default value  for file form, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set default value for `<input type="file"/>` the best thing you can do is when you're updating books table check if request has image if it doesn't then you can skip updating image or reassign previous one

here is what it looks like

```php
DB::table('books')->where('id_book',$request->id_book,$image_name)->update([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'image' => $request->hasFile('image') ? $image_name : $book->image,
    'category' => $request->category,
    'description' => $request->description
]);
```

Comment: What about if I wanna make it required also? It makes it optional

Comment: @ZainShabir you answered your question. if it's always required then it's not optional

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the old file. If you do not change it in the DB and storage when doing the update, it will still there, or will be still null if it was.

You can prepare the array with the data to update from the beginning of the method and add the image element, only if it is present.

```
$data = [
    'title' => $request->title,
    'category' => $request->category,
    'description' => $request->description
];

if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $image_name = time()."_".$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move('img/books',$image_name);
    $data = array_merge($data, ['image' => $image_name]); // here you merge the image name on the data
}

DB::table('books')->where('id_book',$request->id_book)->update($data);
```